# IPv6 doesn't work correctly on AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, ipv6

I configured my Elastic Load Balancer to work as dualstack. I created records set on Route 53 with types A and AAAA pointing to Elastic Load Balancer. Over IPv4, it works

I used this site to test my site over IPv6: [ipv6-test.com/validate.php](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php)

And it returns the following:

[image]

What I need to do to get the others two steps working?

VPC, Subnets and instances are configured to accept IPv6

Edit:

Route table:

[image]

Comment: Did you test an individual instance before you tested the ELB? Did you follow the instructions in the [AWS EC2 IP6 guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html)? You didn't mention security group rules above, you may need to allow IP6 there or your NACLs.

Comment: Yes, I tested and worked. According to Amazon, ELB communicate with instance over IPv4 independently user connection type, however, the instances are configured to accept both. My security groups and NACLs are ok to IPv6 too.

Comment: Not much anyone can do to help you with the information you've given. You're going to have to use a process of elimination.

Comment: I understand.. I tried to search but I didn't found something to help. Maybe someone faced the same issue and found some solution. But thanks to try @Tim

Comment: When you setup the Route53 records pointing to the load balancer did you create the records as ALIAS entries? Does the Route53 entry contain the "dualstack" part?

Comment: Specifically, as @Tim mentioned, the security group associated with the balancer itself needs to allow inbound IPv6 traffic, with rules referencing source address `::/0`.  A rule for `0.0.0.0/0` only allows IPv4.  Do you have this?

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, those are alias and has dualstack part.

Comment: @Michael Yes, the security group has that inbound rule

Comment: One item that I just noticed. There is no check mark next to "IPv6 DNS server". Can you try another IPv6 site that provides more details on your IPv6 configuration? Everything that you describe appears correct. I am leaning towards a DNS issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think you are right. I enabled ping on my ELB and the ping command is working but ping6 isn't.. It returns: ``ping6: UDP connect: No route to host``. But when I use ping6 from my instance, it works. But unfortunately I don't how to solve this

Comment: Post your route table in your question. Add after an ----EDIT---- line.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated the question. Let me know if you need another info

Comment: Are your EC2 instances in a private or public subnet? Your route table has both EIGW and an IGW. The EIGW is for a private subnet. Also you have a static route for "2600:1....". If your EC2 instances are in a public subnet, remove the EIGW and the 2600... static route. If your EC2 instances are in a private subnet, create new a route table for the private subnet and put a NAT Gateway and EIGW in the private subnet route table and remove the EIGW and the 2600 .... from the public route table.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you so much!! I just replace EIGW for IGW and it's working. Provide an answer and I'll mark as solved

Comment: Can you tell me which part of my last answer you implemented? I will then create an answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley sure.. My instances and subnets are public, so I only changed the route table where was ``eigw`` by ``igw``

Comment: If you are not using the EIGW, delete it. I believe that there is a per hour charge.

Comment: Do not delete the 2600xxx static route. Since you had this blacked out I assumed that it was the static IPv6 address of one of your load balancers that you were testing with. This should be your IPv6 local network.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a long thread of comments on this question.

The solution is to change the route table to use the IGW (Internet Gateway) instead of the EIGW (Egress-Only Internet Gateway) to route the IPv6 traffic. Routing the IPv6 traffic thru the EIGW, in effect, makes the load balancers private and not publicly accessible.

Comment: I had also a similar problem. A quick way to test if it's about the VPC settings is to see if `curl -v -6 http::[IPv6 address]/` succeeds from an instance inside the VPC. In my case, it succeeded, so it was about VPC settings.

Comment: I wasn`t using EIGW but turns out my VPC routing table was missing a gateway row for IPv6. It had only 0.0.0.0/0 set to igw-12345678. Once I added row ::/0, also for igw-12345678, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem but without Egress-Only Internet Gateway.

It was happening because my Application Load Balancer was configured with 
ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01 and ipv6-test.com only supports up to ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08.